# When using prepOverlay, how can multiple overlays be prevented from opening?

Tags: jquery, plone, plone-4.x

I'm using Plone 4.3 and I have a browserview where I have links that open up an overlay of a specific form
In my html, I have

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='.prep_form'>Sun</th>
            <th class='.prep_form'>Mon</th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in my jquery file

```
jquery(function($){
    ...
    $('.prep_form').prepOverlay({
        subtype: 'ajax',
        filter: '#content-core > form',
        noform: 'redirect',
        redirect: function(){
            redirect_location = ""; // put together a string
            return redirect_location;
        },
    });
    ...
});
```

Unfortunately, I can click the links multiple times before the form overlay opens, which leads to more than one opening.

How can I prevent more than one overlay from opening?

Comment: Can you measure, how long the xhr requests take? Sounds to me like, it takes very long to load the overlay.

Comment: According to firebug, I am unfortunately taking about little over half a second.  I'll keep that in mind so that the user has less of a chance to double click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Docs](http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/overlay/index.html) of jquery tools is a option for Overlay:`oneInstance:true`
But it should be the default value. You can close all open Overlays via `this.getOverlay().close()`

```
$('.prep_form').prepOverlay({
    subtype: 'ajax',
    filter: '#content-core > form',
    noform: 'redirect',
    redirect: function(){
        redirect_location = ""; // put together a string
        return redirect_location;
    },
    config: {
        oneInstance:true,
        onBeforeLoad : function (e) {
            console.log('onBeforeLoad', this.getOverlay());                
            this.getOverlay().close();
            return true;
        }
    }        
});
```

Comment: I apologize for my late response.  Thank you for your response.  This did solve my problem.